# How can I get this in ie9?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have the following code and I want to know if there is any way to make it compatible with IE9.

The idea is to have two columns with the same height (take the height of the tallest item in the same row) and a content positioned at the bottom of one of the columns.

```css
[class*=col_]{
float:left;position:relative;min-height:1px;margin:0;background-color:lime;}
.col_16{width:66.666666666667%;}
.col_8{width:33.333333333333%;}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    item-align: stretch;
}
.container-title {
    background-color:blue;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-title {
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="col_8">
        <div class="container-title">
            <div class="content-title">
                <p>left content</p>
                <p>left content</p>
                <p>left content</p>
                <p>left content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_16">
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
        <p>right content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use jquery to make ie compatible..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I get it with jQuery? I would like to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make it compatible with both which,  may not be easy (probably not easily), it may be an option to  check/detect the IE version(s) and then load a separate style sheet specially for your issue

```
  <head>
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-down.css" />
  <![endif]-->
```

**lt**   is less than,  you can change it if you want to target ie9 only, it's way simpler than trying to make it work using js. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: IE 10 doesn't support conditional comments so I don't think IE 10 would work although I could be wrong. Maybe `lte IE9` would be better?

Comment: the condition is less that ie10 so ie9 would see that as true and load the css below

Comment: Good point saj... technically  lt IE 11, lt IE 12, lt Ie 13, lt IE 14, and so on should all work as well. Just to keep things making sense and short `<!--[if IE]>` makes the most sense to use at this point in my opinion. On a good note Microsoft will be [dropping support for IE 8, 9, and 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) as of next Tuesday so hopefully we wont have to worry about this nonsense for much longer!